# List on C++ object

Tags: c++, list, oop, object

Hello I want to create list structure, but I don't want to use structures but I want to use objects. I'm newbe and when I do this code it's not working.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

class List {
    public:
        int id;
        List* next = NULL;
        List* prev = NULL;;

        static List create(int value, int id = 0){
            List list;
            list.value = value;
            list.next = NULL;
            list.prev = NULL;
            list.id = id;
            return list;
        }

        void add(int value){
            this->next = &List::create(value, this->id + 1);
        }

        void show(){
            cout << "#" << this->id << endl << "  " << this->value << endl;
            if (this->next != NULL){
                cout << (*this->next).id;
            }
            else{
                cout << "NE ESTAS";
            }
        }

    protected:
        int value;
};

int main(void){
    cout << "Hello, It's a simple Object Lists program" << endl << endl;
    List head = List::create(1);
    head.add(2);
    head.show();
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to check `list.next` address is equal in `create()` method and `show()` but values is different. What I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in the following line, is that you don't really create a new item. You just return a `List`, and copy it into head:

```
List head = List::create(1);
```

Similarly, when you `add()` to head, the following line will return a temporary `List` object.  In `next`, you take the address of this temporary:

```
this->next = &List::create(value, this->id + 1);
```

Unfortunately, this temporary object is subsequently destroyed (when you leave the statement).  So as soon as the add is finished, `next` points to an already invalid object.

When you then call `show()`, you get an undefined behaviour when you try to display the content of `next` (because it points to an object which doesn't exist anymore).

**Some tips for a possible solution:**

The easiest way would be to use [`std::list`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/).... But I guess, you'd like to craft your own `List` in order to learn how this works.

As your intent is to work in an object oriented way,  you should consider the use of a constructor instead of a static creation function:

```
    List (int value, int id = 0) : value(value), 
             id(id), next(nullptr), prev (nullptr) {
    }
```

The add function could be created like this:

```
    void add(int value){
        next = new List (value, id + 1);   // dynamic allocation
        next->prev = this;  
    }
```

Of course this is only the beginning. There's a couple of things you'll need to do:

- create a destructor.  The main question would be:  do you want to destroy only a List, or do you want do destroy also it's followers ?
- create a copy constructor (in order to duplicate List elements and avoid a shallow copy)
- create an assignment operator (same as above, because of the rule of 3)

Answer (score 1):

Here,

```
void add(int value){
    this->next = &List::create(value, this->id + 1);
}
```

You are storing the address of a temporary object. `this->next` is a dangling pointer when the function returns.

You need to allocate an object using dynamic memory and assign it to `this->next`.

```
void add(int value){
    List* ptr = new List;
    ptr->value = value;
    ptr->next = NULL;
    ptr->prev = NULL;
    ptr->id = this->id + 1;

    // Establish the pointer links between this and ptr
    List* next = this->next;

    this->next = ptr;
    ptr->prev = this;

    ptr->next = next;
    if ( next != NULL )
    {
       next->prev = ptr;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your create function:

```
   static List create(int value, int id = 0){
        List list;
        list.value = value;
        list.next = NULL;
        list.prev = NULL;
        list.id = id;
        return list;
    }
```

The object `list` is allocated on the stack (as auto variable) and will hence be destroyed as soon as the function returns. Hence, your return object is already dead and undefined as soon the function returns.

Btw: The class name `List` is a misnomer. You should better call it `Node`, as it represents just one node of a list. You need a separate class for the list itself and that one should be called `List`.

And several functions are incomplete (`add` and `show`), but you probably know that.